# Unable to load an image from an URL in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, url, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I can't seem to figure out why I haven't been able to load any sort of image (I've tried multiple URLs). I've tried using an AsyncTask class, and the issue still hasn't been resolved. My adapter class is listed below, any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to load an image (in this test case, the same image) for each RecyclerView entry. The default view (an orange square) appears when I don't attempt to set an image derived from URL, but if I do attempt it, the ImageView is simply left blank.

**EntryAdapter**

```
public class EntryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EntryAdapter.EntryViewHolder> {
private Entry[] mDataset;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class EntryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public String source;
    public TextView textContent, title, label, author;
    public ImageView thumbnail;
    public CardView topCard, mainCard;
    public EntryViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textContent = v.findViewById(R.id.textContent);
        topCard = v.findViewById(R.id.top_card);
        mainCard = v.findViewById(R.id.main_card);
        thumbnail = mainCard.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        author = mainCard.findViewById(R.id.author);
        label = topCard.findViewById(R.id.label);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public EntryAdapter(Entry[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public EntryAdapter.EntryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                 int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.entry_item_constraints, parent, false);

    EntryViewHolder vh = new EntryViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EntryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.title.setText(mDataset[position].getTitle());
    holder.label.setText(mDataset[position].getLabel());
    holder.textContent.setText(mDataset[position].getTextContent());
    holder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromWebOperations(mDataset[position].getThumbnail()));
    holder.author.setText(mDataset[position].getAuthor());

    //new DownloadImageTask(holder.thumbnail).execute(mDataset[position].getThumbnail());
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "reddit_thumbnail");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try using picasso for image retrieval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`Glide`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to show images in `RecyclerView` which handles lazy loading for scrolling the list smoother. Also it cancels loading operation when the list is scrolled to make the performance and resource consumption better.

```
Glide.with(holder.thumbnail.getContext())
         .load(mDataset[position].getThumbnail())
         .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

In app level **build.gradle:**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

You can also use `placeholder()` method to specify an image (it may point to a drawable using resource id for example) to show it when the target image is not downloaded or unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, it's still just showing the default when I run the app. Is this expected behavior for when the image file is too large? I seriously doubt it is, though.

Comment: You're welcome :) If the image size is too large, it is reasonable to take a longer time for downloading it. Glide resizes and caches the images in required size for next time usage. However, please check the image url using your browser to be sure it exists.

Comment: Yeah, the url brings me to an image. Is there a specific type of image that I have to link to?

Comment: Sure: https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/846659478120366082/K-kZVvT8_400x400.jpg

Comment: It seems that everything is ok :-| Please pass a resource image to glide and check everything else. (like: `Glide.with(holder.thumbnail.getContext()).load(R.drawable.somthing).into(holder.thumbnail);`)

Comment: Wait I see what I did! I forgot I put a tint on the ImageView, which completely blocked the image. Thank you so much!